# Kotlin sequence function unresolved reference

Tags: kotlin, lazy-sequences

- Kotlin 1.0.0
- IDEA 2016.1

I have found a couple of references to the new `sequence` function used to create a sequence (no longer called `stream`).  [The JetBrains blog](http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/03/kotlin-m11-is-out/) gives the following examples:

```
val elements = sequence(1, { x -> x + 1})
val elements = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4).sequence()
```

[The AgileWombat blog](http://agilewombat.com/2016/02/06/kotlin-sequences/) gives similar examples.

```
val squares = sequence(1) {it + 1}.map {it * it}
```

However, when I try any of these examples, either in the REPL or in the IDE (IDEA 2016.1), I get the following:

```
>>> val squares = sequence(1) {it + 1}.map {it * it}
error: unresolved reference: sequence
val squares = sequence(1) {it + 1}.map {it * it}
              ^
error: unresolved reference: it
val squares = sequence(1) {it + 1}.map {it * it}
                           ^
```

I have the latest plugin for the IDE and the latest kotlin package downloaded.  So I must be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This function used to be named `sequence` but the name was changed to `generateSequence` starting from `1.0.0` release. `Iterable<T>.sequence` was renamed to `Iterable<T>.asSequence` as well:

```
val elements = generateSequence(1) { x -> x + 1 }
val elements = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4).asSequence()
```